# formula to count blanks in a new row every day

Tags: excel

I want to count the blank columns in a row, but only for today's date.  I figured using `COUNTBLANK` was the best option but I cant see how to increment the rows.

I uploaded a snippet of the summary sheet that we're using. Within the workbook there's about 20 sheets that need daily updating, and I wanted to have a cell that lets the user know if they omitted entering data into a particular cell.

The cells on the summary sheet aren't actually blank, they all have `VLOOKUP` formulas in them.

[image: Snippet of Summary Sheet]

Comment: Use Countifs and have date as one criteria. You can use dynamic named ranges to handle the new rows.

Comment: Is this a formula i could input into one cell that would auto update the value, or would i have to copy it down into a new row.

Comment: How are new rows being added?

Comment: A new sheet is done for every year. They fill out the A Column with dates for the year, and just add data daily.

Comment: why not pre-populate with all the dates?

Comment: It is prepopulated, but I worked out a solution. I just added a count column and hid it, and am using vlookup with the date to get the count for every row.